# Which is the most efficient framework for Semantic Analysis in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, semantic-analysis

My product is made in Python and I need Semantic Analysis for classification of sentences into questions, complaints, etc. Which is the best framework for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be, try several methods, cross-validated each method using a separate validation data set (or using K-Fold cross-validation) and pick the best one.

So as a starting point you can try:

1. Simple Logistic Regression using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)
2. [Random Forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) or [Gradient Boosting Tree](http://Gradient%20Boosting%20Tree)
3. Recurrent Neural Networks using [Keras](http://keras.io/) library.